# Need to compare a certain cell in contiguous rows and find rows where the value of that cell changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an html table generated dynamically from a database. Rows where a particular cell value is the same represents paired data and I want to separate those pairs with an empty row. The best way I can think of is to find where that value differs from the preceding value. Is this possible?

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
    <th>Team #</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
 </tr>
<tbody>
    <tr class="data-in-table">
        <td class="id">12345</td>
        <td>Tom</td>
        <td>46</td>
       <tr class="data-in-table">
        <td class="id">12345</td>
        <td>Dick</td>
        <td>32</td>
    <tr class="data-in-table">
        <td class="id">34567</td>
        <td>Harry</td>
        <td>45</td>
     <tr class="data-in-table">
        <td class="id">76543</td>
        <td>Will</td>
        <td>45</td>
     </tr>
   <tr class="data-in-table">
        <td class="id">76543</td>
        <td>Sam</td>
        <td>45</td>
     </tr>

</tbody>
```

This is code I've seen comparing adjacent cells and tried to change for my needs:

```
 $("#myTable").each(function () {

    $(this).find('tr').each(function (index) {
    var currentRow = $(this);
    var nextRow = $(this).next('tr').length > 0 ? $(this).next('tr') : null;
    if (index%2==0&&nextRow && currentRow(td[0].text() !=     nextRow(td[0].text()) {
  $('#myTable tr:next').after('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
    }
});
});
```

I'd like it to look something like this:

```
Team #  Name    Age
12345   Tom     46
12345   Dick    32

34567   Harry   45

76543   Will    45
76543   Sam     45
```

As the database updates, team members will always be positioned adjacent to each other, but sometimes one teammate will appear before the second teammate and the table should reflect that.

Comment: its will helpful if you include your code(what you have done ) into the question for us to answer

Comment: You need more detail about how you are rendering your table.

Comment: This really seems like something that should be done in a backend service. We also need more info about things like priority. For example, if Will, Sam, and Sid are all 45, but Sid is on team 12345, where is Sid grouped?

Comment: The only grouping will be by Team #.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this works, through trial and error:

```
var last = ''
var rowCount = $('#myTable >tbody >tr').length;
for (var i=0;i<rowCount-1;i++) {
if (last != $('#myTable tr .id:eq('+i+')').html()) {
var lastRow = $('#myTable tr .id:eq('+i+')')
$(lastRow).parents('tr').before('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>')
}
var last = $('#myTable tr .id:eq('+i+')').html()
 }
```

I don't know if there is a more efficient way than using a for.. statement to run through each row.

Comment: The -1 seems a little harsh considering I revised the question and provided the answer.